# Anyone having the same problem with Facebook/Android not showing photo's uploaded from the phone

Tags: 2.1-eclair, facebook, photos

Has anyone noticed the problem when uploading photo's to **Facebook** using the **Facebook for Android** application ?

I uploaded photo's last week , and they displayed ok in FB/Android.

I did the same this weekend (uploading photo's using FB/Android), and now they are not visible in FB/Android (just showing the brown image place holder), although they are uploaded and displaying fine on FB/Windows .

My collegue noticed the same here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a couple of days a noticed too, that some pictures from Facebook are not shown. If I login later they will show up, but other pictures will not.

I saw a news that they made some changes to photos infrastructure so it's possible to be a temporary outage until they consolidate the new changes on all servers.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that a few random photos will not display even when selecting them using different browsers in mobile mode. But reload using desktop setting and all fb photos display fine. I've removed both fb messenger and fb app due to them being so flaky. There's more stable ways to use fb on Android. My new Android rule is not to use an app where a browser can perform the same task, sometimes less convenient but always more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take your picture first, then upload it to Facebook via the Share button in the gallery app.

Comment: ABryan Denny: That does not make a difference.